# Nested Modules on Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-autoloader

Can we have multiple modules inside another module?

May be a similar structure like this:

```
/module
    /Application
        /module
             /SubApplication1
             /SubApplication2
```

I am looking for an simple example or a article someone know about this. I have googled for reference but seems like this portion of zf2 is not explored so far.

Comment: There's a way to use multiple namespaces in one module, it's very simple. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777140/multiple-namespaces-under-same-module-in-zf2/15779461#15779461) to see how you can do it. To do what you willing to do I think you would have to do a lot of work with the `ModuleManager`.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to have multiple namespaces within your module. The only thing you need to do is to provide configuration to the Zend Autoloader(s). For the `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader` the config can be set in the module and would look something like this:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                // This is the default namespace most probably the module dir name
                __NAMESPACE__    => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                // And this is for your custom namespace within the module
                'SomeNamespace'  => __DIR__ . '/src/' . 'SomeNamespace',
                'OtherNamespace' => __DIR__ . '/src/' . 'OtherNamespace',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

For the `Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader` it is the same concept. You just need to match the namespaces to the class files:

```
// file: ~/autoload_classmap.php
return array(
    'SomeNamespace\Controller\SomeController'    => __DIR__ . '/src/SomeNamespace/Controller/SomeController.php',
    'OtherNamespace\Controller\OtherController'  => __DIR__ . '/src/OtherNamespace/Controller/OtherController.php',
);
```

Something to be caution about! Make sure that your submodule namespace's name doesn't collide with other modules namespaces.

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan