# How can I get multiple subfolder/namespaces in a ZF2 module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Let me start out by saying that I am relatively new to the Zend Framework. I am trying to create an API using ZF2, and to do this I am trying to set up a structure which allows me to group resources. In almost all of the examples I went through, I've seen that people use a standard setup:

```
ModuleA
  ->src
    ->ModuleA
      ->Controller
      ->Entity
```

I am however not a big fan of the "sock drawer" approach, and like to group things. This is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: ZF2 module structure]

Each Controller and Entity folder has it's own Controller and Entity class. In the Module.php I am adding the different namespaces to the AutoLoader like so:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                'User' => __DIR__ . '/src/User',
                'Permission'   => __DIR__ . '/src/Permission',
                'Group'  => __DIR__ . '/src/Group',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

I have setup my module.config.php like:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Auth\Controller\User' => 'User\Controller\UserController',
        'Auth\Controller\Permission' => 'Permission\Controller\PermissionController',
        'Auth\Controller\Group' => 'Group\Controller\GroupController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'user' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user[/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Auth\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

And my UserController looks like:

```
<?php
namespace Auth\User\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use User\Entity\UserTable;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

class UserController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
protected $_objectManager;

public function indexAction()
{
   $users = $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository('\User\Entity\User')->findAll();
   $JSONArray = [];
   //Convert to JSON objects
   foreach ($users as $entity) {
       $JSONArray[] = $entity->getJsonData();
    }
    return new JsonModel(array('users' => $JSONArray));
}
```

I have tried a lot of different cases with namespaces, but I keep on getting a 404 not found error. I've gone through this post:

[Multiple namespaces under same module in ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777140/multiple-namespaces-under-same-module-in-zf2)

Which tells me that I am on the right track, but I am not sure why my path isn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually quite easy; the 404 error that I got was from Apache rather than from Zend. I didn't mention this in the original post since I did not know that Zend had its own error handling system. In my httpd-vhost.conf, I had AllowOverride none set. This meant that the index.php was working, but any other requests didn't get processed by Zend because it couldn't override with the .htaccess file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName api.localhost
     DocumentRoot "path/to/public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
     CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
     <Directory "path/to/public/">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All <- this was AllowOverride none
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
         Require local
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The comment from Tim Fountain on the original post was also something that had to be fixed before I got a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration and your actual class don't match up. You've declared the controller class as `Auth\User\Controller\UserController`, but everything in your config suggests you actually want it to be just `User\Controller\UserController`. If so, change the namespace declaration in your class to:

```
namespace User\Controller;
```

If it still doesn't work after that, we'll need some more info: what path is giving you the 404, and what specifically does the 404 page say the error is (controller class not found?)

Comment: Ah yes, that was something that I definitely missed. But it was not the reason why it was not working. I've answered my own question if anyone has the same setup/issue.